# Arrange the Images loaded from Api into two columns in Flutter using ListTile()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have successfully loaded JSON data from an API to the Flutter app. The JSON data consist of a list of images. The JSON data is in the following format.

```
{
    "images":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "images":"http://url_1.jpg"

    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "images":"http://url_3.jpg"

    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "images":"http://url_4.jpg"

    },
    {
        "id":5,
        "images":"https://url_5.jpg"

    }
]
}
```

And I have loaded the data to a list using the following code fragment and it works fine.

```
_fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    }); //setState
    final response = await http.get("http://192.168.43.95:3000/memes");
    print("response");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      list = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      print(list);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load photos');
    }
  }
```

And I have displayed the images with the following block of code :

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    leading: Image.network(
                      list[index]['images'],
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  );
                })
```

Now I need to modify the above code such that the screen is divided into 2 Columns. Images should be placed in these columns (width of the 2 columns are the same) with the height of each image is proportional to its width. Also, as we scroll down the remaining images should load into these two columns. **Similar to google image search results in chrome**

What are the changes need to be made? If this is not possible with ListTile(), how can I do it?
[image]

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: @Eugene Thanks. It was the stuff I was looking for

Comment: people giving negative votes please mention the reason so that it can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked fine for me. The **crossAxisCount:2** split into two columns and **StaggeredTile.fit(1)** fits each tile into one column.

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
                        child: Image(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image: NetworkImage(list[index]['image']))),
              staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => new StaggeredTile.fit(1),
            ),
```

Answer (score 3):

use **flutter_staggered_grid_view: "^0.2.7"** from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view/versions/0.2.7)

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Card(
      elevation: 5.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(list[index]['images']),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
        new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1.5),
    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: can you please explain the important properties.

Comment: what is the significance of crossAxisCount: 4 and staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1.5),

Answer (score 1):

You should use [flutter_staggered_grid_view 0.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

[See example.](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view/tree/master/example)

[image]